# What is the difference between "use case" and "function"?

Tags: graphical-models

In the use case diagram, we draw use cases as an ellipse. Are the use cases the same as functions? I mean by functions, those functions which we write in the program.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use case enable you to visualize the different types of roles in a system,however,a function defines a procedure or routine. Some programming languages make a distinction between a function, which returns a value, and a procedure, which performs some operation but does not return a value.

Comment: This is actually an English question.

Answer (score 1):

If by "function" you mean functionality then a single use case may require more than one function to achieve and a single function may serve multiple use cases.

Here's a concrete example:

**Use case**:

- Allow user to withdraw money

**Functions**:

- Check user balance
- Prompt user to enter amount and check against balance
- Check amount against money in machine
- Output money

Depending on how you go about documenting your design you can argue that the 4 functions above can be written as a single function. Though doing this misses the important realization that `Check user balance` is a function that can be reused in another use case (`Allow user to see his balance`), even if we reduce them to one function the use case and function would be different ways to say the same thing:

**Use case:**

- Allow user to withdraw money

**Function**:

- Withdraw money

So, at its core level a **functionality** is an implementation of processes for a **use case**.

Why do we need two different names? Sometimes it makes it clearer to talk about a requirement and the solution to it. Similar to how in programming we have **classes** and **objects**.

Answer (score 0):

The word *function* has several meanings. One of them is similar to the meaning of *use case*. Another is *mathematical function*. Yet another is *computer routine*. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/function#English) lists a few more.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience use case is what the code is used for and function is what the code does. For example you may have a subroutine that calculates the length of the minnimal path between two nodes in a graph but a specific use case may be to find the minimal length between two points in a maze (when represented as a graph).